# merging 2 nested lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to merge 2 nested lists L1 and L2 into a nested list L3, so far this is what I have and it seems to not work:

```
merge(L,[],L).
merge([],K,K).
merge([X|L],[Y|K],[X|M]) :- X < Y, merge(L,[Y|K],M).
merge([X|L],[Y|K],[Y|M]) :- X >= Y, merge([X|L],K,M).
```

Expected behaviour:

```
?- merge([2,[2,3],[4,5,[5,6,7]]], [[5,[4,3],[2,1]],6,[7,8]], L3).
L3 = [[10, [8,6], [4,2]], [12, 18], [28, 40, [5, 6, 7]]]
```

The trickiest part for me is maintaining the structure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to indicate when it does not work. Also, note that `merge([],[],[])` succeeds twice!

Comment: @false basically I think its not succeeding because there is no base case for a nested list, and I think its expecting ordered lists.

Comment: Are the values supposed to be multiplied pairwise? I think you need to explain the sense of "merge" you are using.

Comment: @TomasBy it's a tree merge so if the roots of L1 is 2 and the root of L2 is 5 then the root of the resulting tree L3 will be 10 and so on. So based on the level of the nesting we combine the numbers through multiplication.

Comment: When you wrote `X < Y` did you consider that your `X` or `Y` can be a list?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I didn't consider that, and I think that part shouldn't be there, since I care about the nesting not the order

Comment: What should happen if they have a different number of children at some node (more general case of previous comment I guess) ?

Comment: And why the test at all? Shouldn't there be a multiplication somewhere?

Comment: @TomasBy there should be multiplication somewhere but I didn't know where

Comment: @TomasBy merging a leaf node with a subtree is done by scaling the subtree by the value of the leaf.

Comment: the assumption here is that I am dealing with numbers

Comment: Well that's four cases then, for neither list empty, not two. And you need three, not two, for at least one list empty.

Comment: @TomasBy can you please show me how it's going to work out

Comment: can anyone please post what they came up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
merge([X|L],[Y|K],[Z|M]) :-
  ( is_list(X), is_list(Y) ->
    merge(X,Y,Z)
  ; is_list(X) ->
    scale(Y,X,Z)
  ; is_list(Y) ->
    scale(X,Y,Z)
  ; Z is X * Y ),
  merge(L,K,M).
merge(L,[],L) :- L \= [].
merge([],K,K) :- K \= [].
merge([],[],[]).

scale(F,[H0|T0],[H|T]) :-
  ( is_list(H0) ->
    scale(F,H0,H)
  ; H is F * H0 ),
  scale(F,T0,T).
scale(_,[],[]).
```